# Libgdx the good way of dealing with fonts

Tags: fonts, libgdx

Dealing with fonts is a nightmare.

It seems in libgdx that bitmapfont is the only way to write on the screen.

I tried several ways.

1) Generating the fonts thanks to the FreetypeFontGenerator when the app start.

- (+) Perfect scaling, the fonts render perfectly
- (-) My app needs 14 seconds to start...

2) Generating only one bitmapFont for every different ttf font I need and scaling them in label later.

- (+) Quicker
- (-) Ugly. And is quicker because I only have 2 different fonts. If I had more, event one of each would takes forever to be generated

3) Generating them in advanced with hiero

- (+) It would probably work well, i guess
- (-) I couldn't event do that since Hiero limit the size to 256px and I want to display a big countdown taking half of the screen height (735px)

4) Use png instead of fonts.

- (+) Quicker, I guess
- (-) Same scaling problem than 2, and can't change text at runtime, obviously.

The (3) really makes me think that if a software dedicated to bitmapfont doesn't allow me to create fonts larger thant 256, then it means that I am the one doing things wrong.

But I just can't understand what to do. I mean look at web browers for example. If I want, I can just press f12, select a text and set font-size: 1000px. It will instantly render a perfect looking text. No pixelisation and no never ending loading.

I know, chrome and my game have not been created with the same technology, the same library.

But is it really the problem ? The library ?

I really, really hope it's not, I hope I am the problem, I hope than there is something I'm doing wrong and I can learn.

So, here is the question :

What is the best, the proper way of dealing with fonts ?

Comment: I don't know of any game engine that has vector support for fonts like web browsers do. Generate your fonts the first time the app loads, and save them to internal. Load the BitmapFont directly from the files on all subsequent loads. http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=19476&p=81651

Comment: For very large fonts like your countdown timer, use Heiro and make a distance field font so it can scale up near-infinitely without pixelation. Then your actual image files for the font can be quite small and take up little memory. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts Depending on the font you use, you might be able to simply do this for everything and it would be the cleanest solution.

Comment: If you're curious why games never have vector font rendering support, it's because GPU's aren't well suited for it: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191472/why-have-hardware-accelerated-vector-graphics-not-taken-off

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try out the distance field font. And thank you for the link, I am, indeed, very curious.

Comment: I would not generate a font to show a countdown timer that big at all. If I would go for something that big I would take the time to hand draw the numbers or a fancy timer and make it look stunning. For all other tasks I personally use hiero and with a normal font, a bit of downscaling is perfectly fine. I never used the ftf-generator since just bitmap fonts work perfectly for me, even for some fancy text. Anyway, creating games, especially indie games, is a lot about making compromises.

Comment: @MennoGouw Thank you, it's nice to have advice. What do you call a bit of downscaling ? Does it mean you have a single large bitmap font you use for every resolutions and which you scale or you generate with hiero several times the same font with different sizes to fit the closest resolution? And you may scale a bit those font sometimes. The first option is kinda disappointing, at least with the fonts I'm using ^^, so I would guess the second ?

Comment: For most of my project I have just one bitmap. Whenever I need slightly smaller text I just scale like .75. This seems to work for me but then again I can barely see the difference on my phone between 720p and 1080p so it might just be me that has perfect anti aliasing sampling build into my eyes ;).

Comment: Alright ! I will meditate everything :)